# Regex Pattern Comprising From the Elements in List

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make a script that reads the list element sequentially and concatenate them each into regex pattern.

for example,

I have a list like this:

```
lst = ['B.', 'Article', 'III']
```

And want to comprise regex something like this:

```
re.search(r lst[0]\s+lst[1]\s+lst[2]).group()
```

so that it can match below regardless of white_spaces between each elements from the list:

```
candidate_1 = 'B.      Article III'
candidate_2 = 'B.        Article III'
```

Comment: Ok. We wish you the best of luck

Comment: @sshashank124 thx I really hope so :D

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Robᵩ I don't know how to concatenate r with str. if I do r lst[0]\s+lst[1]\s+lst[2] it reutrns error, and if I do rlst[0]\s+lst[1]\s+lst[2] it also definitely returns error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), like so:

```
r'\s+'.join(lst)
```

Here is a complete program:

```
import re

def list2pattern(l):
    return r'\s+'.join(l)

lst = ['B.', 'Article', 'III']
assert re.search(list2pattern(lst), 'B. Article III')
assert re.search(list2pattern(lst), 'B.      Article III')
assert not re.search(list2pattern(lst), 'B.Article III')
assert not re.search(list2pattern(lst), 'George')
```

Comment: I have more fundamental question. I have tried type(list2pattern(lst)) and it returns str, where my question is then, how the machine distinguish between str and r str if they are all memorized as str?

Comment: @delinco: What are "str" and "r str"? Ah, probably you mean `r""`: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals.

Comment: the r that always added before expressing regex pattern

Comment: @delinco - See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals